# Prevent spring to default to session authentication when using JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application which is secured by Azure AD oauth2. I use JWT authorization.
in securityConfig

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
```

I also save some things inside session. But I found out that users can bypass JWT authentication if they already authenticated, because spring boot saves authentication inside session. How Can I disable this behavior and only allow authorization via JWT.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

Comment: Will I still be able to save things inside session? Because I use session to save some properties